# How to fix ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null?

Tags: typescript

I need to fix this line of code :

I got error :

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null

I am try with :

But also same error message.

Without ! I have error message:

> Object is possibly 'null'.ts(2531)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `?` instead of `!` and change with `get` vs `getAll`:

```
JSON.parse(data.headers.get('x-pagination')?.split(',')?.[0]);
```

Note the `.` as well when using `?` with `[..]` accessor

Edit: `getAll` is deprecated and `get` returns all the values of a header as a comma separated string.

Comment: When use get Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

Comment: When use getAll()?.[0]  -> Retrieves a list of values for a given header. 
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
http.d.ts(3061, 12): An argument for 'name' was not provided.

Comment: JSON.parse(data.headers.get('x-pagination')?.split(',')?.[0]);  -> Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 0):

That means you are trying to access a value `[0]` of an object that may be `null`, which could cause you errors when that's the case.

As suggested by @Tobin, you could easily add the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), aka `?.` to fix the error, but in that case you could end up trying to parse undefined values.

Add a condition instead, wrapping all the stuff / logic related with that header:

```js
const pagHeader = data.headers.getAll('x-pagination')

if (pagHeader) {
  // Your other related logic here
  JSON.parse(pagHeader[0])
  // Your other related logic here
}
```

This will help ensuring you trigger that logic only when the header is present.